# Dereferencing Pointer Error when processing Ip header from raw Sockets

Tags: sockets, raw-sockets, incomplete-type

void parse_message(char *buffer, int len)
{

```
struct iphrd *ip_header = (struct iphrd *)buffer;

int recv_hopcount = (unsigned int)(ip_header->ttl);

//hops[recv_hopcount]++;
```

}

error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

I have include netinet/ip.h in the header file. The above code is written to access the ttl value contained in the IP header. Used raw sockets.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the iphrd struct has not been defined anywhere.  Is it a typo of iphdr? Your issue looks like there is no struct called iphrd...